# SPFx - Provisioning a web part by code on a home page removes other contents

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, spfx, sharepointframework

I'm trying to provision a communication site by using the SharePoint CSOM / REST, and then adding a web part to the home page. The first part (provisioning) works well. However, when I add the web part by using the `SharePointPnPCoreOnline` NuGet package, all existing web parts on the home page are removed.

Here is my provisioning code (simplified for brevity):

```
var homePage = clientContext.Web.LoadClientSidePage("Home.aspx");
var clientSideComponent = homePage.AvailableClientSideComponents()
    .SingleOrDefault(csc => csc.Id.Equals("{<web part ID here>}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
ClientSideWebPart webPart = new ClientSideWebPart(clientSideComponent);
CanvasSection section = new CanvasSection(homePage, CanvasSectionTemplate.OneColumn, 0);
homePage.Sections.Add(section);
homePage.Save();
homePage.AddControl(webPart, section.Columns[0]);
homePage.Save();
homePage.Publish();
```

When the site has just been provisioned, and the home page has not yet been modified:

- The page displays a set of default web parts. For example, if I selected the "Topic" design, I can see

  - A full-width section, containing a "Hero" web part, with five tiles, and some welcome messages and links
  - A "one column" section, containing several web parts: News, Events, Documents, Quick links and People profiles.
- The content of the page, as downloaded from the "SitePages" library, doesn't contain an `<mso:CanvasContent1 />` element, thus it has no explicitly defined web part.
- The content of these web parts comes from the `https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2019-09-20.008/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_36e69c06b20e347fb4426bfdff916a8e.js` file
- The web part content is translated in the current user's language.

After I provision my web part with the preceding code, the web part is present on the page, but all the initial web parts have been removed.

If instead of provisioning the web part automatically, I do it manually:

- The default web parts are kept.
- In the page as stored in "SitePages", I can see the original web parts and my web part in the element `<mso:CanvasContent1 />`.
- The initial content it is not translated anymore, but only available in the language of the user who first edited the page.

So my question is: is there a way to programmatically add a web part to a the home page of a newly provisioned modern site (team or communication), without removing the default web parts ?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to provision explicitly all default web parts. I did it so:
1) do some changes in the page
2) save the content of the CanvasContent1 field
3) store that content in my provisioning solution, replacing specific URLs and IDs with placeholders so it acts as a template
4) when provisioning a new site, replace the placeholders with site-specific IDs and URLs
5) set manually the field "CanvasContent1".